# Tagged Tuple with "special" copying

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

This is my first serious post on any stackexchange so any criticism is welcome.

Github link to the code in this question: https://github.com/yevsev/tagged_tuple

### Problem statement

For a computation pipeline it is quite common to have a sequence of functions where each function transforms the data type to a new type. Example of a small pipeline:

```cpp
ResultType Pipeline(InputType input) {
    FooOutput foo_output = Foo(input);
    BarOutput bar_output = Bar(foo_output);
    return ComputeResult(foo_output, bar_output);
}
```

Now if we add one more step to the pipeline then this can affect everything else:

```
ResultType Pipeline(InputType input) {
    FooOutput foo_output = Foo(input);
    BarOutput bar_output = Bar(foo_output);
    StepOutput step_output = Step(bar_output);
    return ComputeResult(foo_output, bar_output, step_output);
}
```

The new function `Step()` takes `BarOutput` as its argument but it could also have taken `FooOutput` or any combination of the types that are present in the function `Pipeline` (`InputType`, `FooOutput`, `BarOutput`, `ResultType`).
This example illustrates that the problem gets worse with a longer pipeline. It will get even worse when the dependencies between processing steps is not only sequential as in a pipeline, but tree-like. Doing a small refactor on a computation tree can be a lot more difficult then it has to be because of the strict type-safety of function arguments.

The `std::tuple` or variadic templates provide more flexibility but usually at the cost of (the clarity of) compiler errors.

### Proposed solution

A compile-time associative array (tagged tuple) can provide all flexibility that is needed to reduce refactoring cost while maintaining clear compiler errors. The elements of the tagged tuple are gettable by Tag rather than be index which means that the ordering of the tuple becomes irrelevant since each element has its own unique identifier. The flexibility is improved further by allowing the compiler to convert seemingly incompatible collections of types (tuples). Here follow some examples of tuples that are not convertible by default but would be convertible using a tagged tuple:

1. Order of types is different: `std::tuple<int, std::string>` and `std::tuple<std::string, int>`.
   The compiler generates a different type for each tuple but the conversion is arbitrary if each element in the tuple has a unique Tag type since the data are only reordered.
2. Subset of types: `std::tuple<int, std::string>` is a subset of `std::tuple<std::string, float, int>`.
   Here are two possible conversions: converting `std::tuple<int, std::string>` to `std::tuple<std::string, float, int>` which would leave the `float` untouched and vice versa which would not copy the `float`.
3. Intersection of types: `std::tuple<int, std::string, std::vector<bool>>` and `std::tuple<std::string, float, int>` have two types in common.
   Converting `std::tuple<int, std::string, std::vector<bool>>` to `std::tuple<std::string, float, int>` will leave `float` untouch and will not copy `std::vector<bool>` and for the opposite case it will leave `std::vector<bool>` untouched while not copying the `float`.

A copying policy could be used to select what form of conversion is allowed for each instance of the tagged tuple.

The tagged tuple will work exactly like the `std::tuple` but instead of getting elements by index they are gettable by a unique Tag type. In this way, a function `Foo()` that takes a tagged tuple as argument only cares about the existence of some specific types within the tagged tuple, the rest is irrelevant but still there and remains unaffected by whatever is done inside `Foo()`.

This pattern could be useful as sort of a middleware that decouples different steps in a computation tree.
It also becomes a lot easier to add data to the pipeline without affecting the steps of the pipeline.

I would highly appreciate any feedback on the following:

- Anything related to metaprogramming.
- Possible impact on compilation time due to templates and how to improve.
- How to add a copying policy in a clean manner?
- My motivation for why the tagged tuple is useful.

### Implementation

Only tested with GCC 8.3.0

I created a working implementation of a tagged_tuple at the bottom of this post but first a toy example to show how different steps in a computation become decoupled:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include "tagged_tuple.hpp"

struct Tag1;
struct TagTimestamp;
struct TagTemperature;
struct TagPressure;
struct TagCameraFrame;
struct CameraFrame4K {int big_data;};
template<typename... Ts>
tt::tagged_tuple<Ts..., TagTemperature, unsigned int> TemperatureSensor(tt::tagged_tuple<Ts...> const& in, unsigned int temperature) {
    tt::tagged_tuple<Ts..., TagTemperature, unsigned int> out = in;
    tt::get<TagTemperature>(out) = temperature;
    tt::get<TagTimestamp>(out) += 1;
    return out;
}
template<typename... Ts>
void TemperatureSensor(tt::tagged_tuple<Ts...> * data, unsigned int temperature) {
    tt::get<TagTemperature>(*data) = temperature;
    tt::get<TagTimestamp>(*data) += 1;
}
template<typename... Ts>
tt::tagged_tuple<Ts..., TagPressure, unsigned int> PressureSensor(tt::tagged_tuple<Ts...> const& in, unsigned int pressure) {
    tt::tagged_tuple<Ts..., TagPressure, unsigned int> out = in;
    tt::get<TagPressure>(out) = pressure;
    tt::get<TagTimestamp>(out) += 1;
    return out;
}
template<typename... Ts>
tt::tagged_tuple<Ts..., TagCameraFrame, CameraFrame4K> CameraSensor(tt::tagged_tuple<Ts...> const& in, CameraFrame4K frame) {
    tt::tagged_tuple<Ts..., TagCameraFrame, CameraFrame4K> out = in;
    tt::get<TagCameraFrame>(out) = frame;
    tt::get<TagTimestamp>(out) += 1;
    return out;
}
template<typename... Ts>
bool Actuator(tt::tagged_tuple<Ts...>& in) {
    unsigned int pressure = tt::get<TagPressure>(in);
    unsigned int temperature = tt::get<TagTemperature>(in);

    // Do some processing based on data
    if (pressure >= 228 && temperature <= 5) {
        std::cout << "Supercritical Helium\n";
        return true;
    } else {
        unsigned int temperature = tt::get<TagTemperature>(in);
        TemperatureSensor(&in, temperature-1);
        std::cout << "Lowering temperature: " << temperature << "K\n";
        return false;
    }
}
template<typename... Ts>
void Plant(tt::tagged_tuple<Ts...>& in) {
    while(!Actuator(in)) {

    }
}

template<typename T>
void ExpectEq(T const& a,T  const& b) {
    if (a != b) {
        std::cerr << "Values not equal" << "\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    // t1 contains TagTimestamp and Tag1
    tt::tagged_tuple<TagTimestamp, int, Tag1, float> t1;

    // t2 contains the same types as t1 but TagTemperature was added by the sensor
    auto t2 = TemperatureSensor(t1, 25);
    ExpectEq(t1.get<TagTimestamp>()+1, t2.get<TagTimestamp>());

    // t3 contains the same types as t1 and t2 but TagPressure was added by the sensor
    auto t3 = PressureSensor(t2, 567);
    ExpectEq(t2.get<TagTimestamp>()+1, t3.get<TagTimestamp>());

    // Function Actuator will take any tagged_tuple that contains TagPressure and TagTemperature
    Actuator(t3);

    // Fancy new machine with camera
    auto t4 = CameraSensor(t3, {12345});
    ExpectEq(t3.get<TagTimestamp>()+1, t4.get<TagTimestamp>());

    // Actuator interface remains completely unchanged.
    // The function still works as expected so long as the correct Tags are present in the tagged_tuple
    Actuator(t4);

    Plant(t4);

}
```

Working implementation of the tagged tuple.

```cpp
#ifndef TAGGED_TUPLE_HPP
#define TAGGED_TUPLE_HPP

#include <tuple>

namespace tt {

// TODO: profile compilation with templight

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///
/// traits
///
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//
//
// List of type, more light-weight than std::tuple
template<typename... Ts>
struct pack {
    template<typename T>
    using push_front = pack<T, Ts...>;
};

//
//
// Check if all bools provided are true
template<bool...>
struct bool_pack;
template <bool... Bools>
using all_true = std::is_same<bool_pack<Bools..., true>, bool_pack<true, Bools...>>;

//
//
// Check if type T is present in Ts...
template<typename...> struct is_one_of;
template<typename T> struct is_one_of<T> : std::false_type {};
template<typename T, typename... Ts> struct is_one_of<T, T, Ts...> : std::true_type {};
template<typename T, typename S, typename... Ts> struct is_one_of<T, S, Ts...> : is_one_of<T, Ts...> {};

// Check if type T is present in pack<Ts...>
template<typename T, typename Pack> struct is_in_pack;
template<typename T, typename... Ts> struct is_in_pack<T, pack<Ts...>> : is_one_of<T, Ts...> {};

//
//
// Get type in Ts... at Idx
template<std::size_t Idx, typename... Ts> struct at;
template<typename T, typename... Ts> struct at<0, T, Ts...> { using type = T; };
template<std::size_t Idx, typename T, typename... Ts> struct at<Idx, T, Ts...> : at<Idx-1, Ts...> {};
template<std::size_t Idx, typename... Ts> using at_t = typename at<Idx, Ts...>::type;

//
//
// Get the index of first occurence of type T in Ts...
template<typename T, typename... Ts> struct find;
template<typename T, typename... Ts> struct find<T, T, Ts...> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0> {};
template<typename T, typename S, typename... Ts> struct find<T, S, Ts...>
        : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, find<T, Ts...>::value+1> {};

//
//
// Get type by tag
template<typename Tag, typename Tags, typename Vals> struct find_by_tag;
template<typename Tag, typename... Tags, typename... Vals>
struct find_by_tag<Tag, pack<Tags...>, pack<Vals...>> : at<find<Tag, Tags...>::value, Vals...> {};
template<typename Tag, typename Tags, typename Vals>
using find_by_tag_t = typename find_by_tag<Tag, Tags, Vals>::type;

//
//
// Check if all types in Ts... are also present in Us...
template<typename Ts, typename Us> struct is_subset_of;
template<typename T, typename... Ts, typename... Us> struct is_subset_of<pack<T, Ts...>, pack<Us...>>
        : all_true<
            is_one_of<T, Us...>::value,
            is_subset_of<pack<Ts...>, pack<Us...>>::value
        > {};
template<typename... Us> struct is_subset_of<pack<>, pack<Us...>> : std::true_type {};

//
//
// Check if each type in Ts... occurs only once
// If Ts... is empty will yield true
template<typename... Ts> struct is_unique;
template<> struct is_unique<> : std::true_type {};
template<typename T> struct is_unique<T> : std::true_type {};
template<typename T> struct is_unique<T, T> : std::false_type {};
template<typename T, typename... Ts> struct is_unique<T, Ts...>
        : all_true<!is_one_of<T, Ts...>::value, is_unique<Ts...>::value> {};

//
//
// Starting at Offset, pick every other Stride type and place in pack
template<std::size_t Offset, std::size_t Stride, typename... Ts> struct pick;
template<std::size_t Offset, std::size_t Stride> struct pick<Offset, Stride> { using types = pack<>; };
template<std::size_t Offset, std::size_t Stride, typename T, typename... Ts> struct pick<Offset, Stride, T, Ts...>
        : pick<Offset - 1, Stride, Ts...> {};
template<std::size_t Stride, typename T, typename... Ts> struct pick<0, Stride, T, Ts...>
{ using types = typename pick<Stride - 1, Stride, Ts...>::types::template push_front<T>; };
template<std::size_t Offset, std::size_t Stride, typename... Ts> using pick_t = typename pick<Offset, Stride, Ts...>::types;

//
template<std::size_t Offset, std::size_t Stride, typename Pack> struct pick_pack;
template<std::size_t Offset, std::size_t Stride, typename... Ts> struct pick_pack<Offset, Stride, pack<Ts...>>
        : pick<Offset, Stride, Ts...> {};
template<std::size_t Offset, std::size_t Stride, typename Pack>
using pick_pack_t = typename pick_pack<Offset, Stride, Pack>::types;

//
//
// Get all types that inherit from S
template<typename S, typename... Ts> struct extract_subtypes;
template<typename S> struct extract_subtypes<S> { using types = pack<>; };
template<typename S, typename T, typename... Ts> struct extract_subtypes<S, T, Ts...> {
    using types = std::conditional_t<
        std::is_base_of<S, T>::value, // TODO: This cannot handle undefined structs
        typename extract_subtypes<S, Ts...>::types::template push_front<T>,
        typename extract_subtypes<S, Ts...>::types
    >;
};
template<typename S, typename... Ts> using extract_subtypes_t = typename extract_subtypes<S, Ts...>::types;

//
//
// Get set difference of pack<Ss...> and pack<Ts...>
// All types in Ss... that are not in Ts...
template<typename Ss, typename Ts> struct diff;
template<typename... Ts> struct diff<pack<>, pack<Ts...>> { using types = pack<>; };
template<typename S, typename... Ss, typename... Ts> struct diff<pack<S, Ss...>, pack<Ts...>> {
    using types = std::conditional_t<
        is_one_of<S, Ts...>::value,
        typename diff<pack<Ss...>, pack<Ts...>>::types,
        typename diff<pack<Ss...>, pack<Ts...>>::types::template push_front<S>
    >;
};
template<typename Ss, typename Ts> using diff_t = typename diff<Ss, Ts>::types;

//
//
// Check if tagged type is in (Tags.../Vals...)
template<typename Tag1, typename Val1,
         typename Tags, typename Vals> struct is_in_tagged_pack;
template<typename Tag_, typename Val_,
         typename... Tags, typename... Vals>
struct is_in_tagged_pack<Tag_, Val_, pack<Tags...>, pack<Vals...>>
        : std::conditional_t<
            all_true<
                is_one_of<Tag_, Tags...>::value,
                is_one_of<Val_, Vals...>::value
            >::value,
            std::is_same<Val_, find_by_tag_t<Tag_, pack<Tags...>, pack<Vals...>>>,
//            std::is_same<Val, at_t<find<Tag, Tags...>::value, Vals...>>,
            std::false_type
        > {};
template<typename Tag_, typename Val_, typename Tag2_, typename Val2_>
struct is_in_tagged_pack<Tag_, Val_, pack<Tag2_>, pack<Val2_>> : std::false_type {};
template<typename Tag_, typename Val_>
struct is_in_tagged_pack<Tag_, Val_, pack<>, pack<>> : std::false_type {};
template<typename Tag_, typename Val_>
struct is_in_tagged_pack<Tag_, Val_, pack<Tag_>, pack<Val_>> : std::true_type {};
//
//
// Check if tagged types (Tags1.../Vals1...) is a subset of tagged types (Tags2.../Vals2...)
template<typename Tags1, typename Vals1,
         typename Tags2, typename Vals2> struct is_subset_of_tagged_impl;
template<typename Tag1_, typename... Tags1,
         typename Val1_, typename... Vals1,
         typename... Tags2, typename... Vals2>
struct is_subset_of_tagged_impl<pack<Tag1_, Tags1...>, pack<Val1_, Vals1...>, pack<Tags2...>, pack<Vals2...>>
        : std::conditional_t<
//            is_one_of<Tag1_, Tags2...>::value,
            is_in_tagged_pack<Tag1_, Val1_, pack<Tags2...>, pack<Vals2...>>::value,
            all_true<
                std::is_same<Val1_, at_t<find<Tag1_, Tags2...>::value, Vals2...>>::value,
                is_subset_of_tagged_impl<pack<Tags1...>, pack<Vals1...>, pack<Tags2...>, pack<Vals2...>>::value
            >,
            std::false_type
        > {};
template<typename Tag1_, typename Val1_,
         typename Tag2_, typename Val2_>
struct is_subset_of_tagged_impl<pack<Tag1_>, pack<Val1_>, pack<Tag2_>, pack<Val2_>>
        : all_true<
            std::is_same<Tag1_, Tag2_>::value,
            std::is_same<Val1_, Val2_>::value
        > {};
template<typename... Tags2, typename... Vals2>
struct is_subset_of_tagged_impl<pack<>, pack<>, pack<Tags2...>, pack<Vals2...>> : std::true_type{};
template<typename Tags1, typename Vals1,
         typename Tags2, typename Vals2> struct is_subset_of_tagged;
template<typename... Tags1, typename... Vals1,
         typename... Tags2, typename... Vals2>
struct is_subset_of_tagged<pack<Tags1...>, pack<Vals1...>, pack<Tags2...>, pack<Vals2...>>
        : std::conditional_t<
            all_true<
                is_subset_of<pack<Tags1...>, pack<Tags2...>>::value,
                is_subset_of<pack<Vals1...>, pack<Vals2...>>::value
            >::value,
            is_subset_of_tagged_impl<pack<Tags1...>, pack<Vals1...>, pack<Tags2...>, pack<Vals2...>>,
            std::false_type
        > {};

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///
/// tagged_tuple
///
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

namespace detail {

//
//
// Each typename T provided to serve as Tag is wrapped in tt::Tag<T>
template<typename T> struct Tag;

//
//
// Types that can be provided as options must inherit from tt::Option
struct Option {};

//template<typename... Ts> using extract_options_t = extract_subtypes_t<Option, Ts...>;
//template<typename... Ts> using extract_tags_values_t = diff_t<pack<Ts...>, extract_options_t<Ts...>>;
//template<typename... Ts> using extract_tags_t = pick_pack_t<0, 2, extract_tags_values_t<Ts...>>;
//template<typename... Ts> using extract_vals_t = pick_pack_t<1, 2, extract_tags_values_t<Ts...>>;
template<typename... Ts> using extract_tags_t = pick_t<0, 2, Ts...>;
template<typename... Ts> using extract_vals_t = pick_t<1, 2, Ts...>;

//
//
//
template<typename Tags, typename Vals>
struct tagged_tuple_impl;

//
//
// Policy structs for deciding what copies are allowed
struct copying_policy_flexible {
    template <typename TagsSrc, typename ValsSrc, typename TagsDst, typename ValsDst>
    struct is_copyable_t;
    template <typename... TagsSrc, typename... ValsSrc, typename... TagsDst, typename... ValsDst>
    struct is_copyable_t<pack<TagsSrc...>, pack<ValsSrc...>, pack<TagsDst...>, pack<ValsDst...>>
            : all_true<
                is_subset_of_tagged<pack<TagsSrc...>, pack<ValsSrc...>, pack<TagsDst...>, pack<ValsDst...>>::value ||
                is_subset_of_tagged<pack<TagsDst...>, pack<ValsDst...>, pack<TagsSrc...>, pack<ValsSrc...>>::value
            >
    {};
    template <template<class,class> class TaggedTuple, typename... TagsSrc, typename... ValsSrc, typename... TagsDst, typename... ValsDst>
    constexpr static bool is_copyable(
            TaggedTuple<pack<TagsSrc...>, pack<ValsSrc...>> /*src*/,
            TaggedTuple<pack<TagsDst...>, pack<ValsDst...>> /*dst*/) {
        return is_copyable_t<pack<TagsSrc...>, pack<ValsSrc...>, pack<TagsDst...>, pack<ValsDst...>>::value;
    }
};

/**
 * @brief copy_from  copy all elements of @param{src} to @param{dst}
 * Copy in case src is subset of dst
 * is_subset_of_tagged<pack<TagsSrc...>, pack<ValsSrc...>, pack<TagsDst...>, pack<ValsDst...>>::value == true
 */
template<std::size_t Idx = 0,
         typename... TagsSrc, typename... ValsSrc,
         typename... TagsDst, typename... ValsDst>
constexpr std::enable_if_t<Idx < sizeof...(TagsSrc), void> copy_from(
        tagged_tuple_impl<pack<TagsSrc...>, pack<ValsSrc...>> const& src,
        tagged_tuple_impl<pack<TagsDst...>, pack<ValsDst...>>& dst) {
    using Tag = at_t<Idx, TagsSrc...>;
    dst.template get<Tag>() = src.template get<Tag>();
    copy_from<Idx + 1>(src, dst);
}
template<std::size_t Idx = 0,
         typename... TagsSrc, typename... ValsSrc,
         typename... TagsDst, typename... ValsDst>
constexpr std::enable_if_t<Idx == sizeof...(TagsSrc), void> copy_from(
        tagged_tuple_impl<pack<TagsSrc...>, pack<ValsSrc...>> const& /*src*/,
        tagged_tuple_impl<pack<TagsDst...>, pack<ValsDst...>>& /*dst*/) {
    // Nothing left to do
}
/**
 * @brief copy_to  for each type in @param{dst} copy the corresponding element from @param{src}
 * Copy in case src is subset of dst
 * is_subset_of_tagged<pack<TagsSrc...>, pack<ValsSrc...>, pack<TagsDst...>, pack<ValsDst...>>::value == true
 */
template<std::size_t Idx = 0,
         typename... TagsSrc, typename... ValsSrc,
         typename... TagsDst, typename... ValsDst>
constexpr std::enable_if_t<Idx < sizeof...(TagsDst), void> copy_to(
        tagged_tuple_impl<pack<TagsSrc...>, pack<ValsSrc...>> const& src,
        tagged_tuple_impl<pack<TagsDst...>, pack<ValsDst...>>& dst) {
    using Tag = at_t<Idx, TagsDst...>;
    dst.template get<Tag>() = src.template get<Tag>();
    copy_to<Idx + 1>(src, dst);
}
template<std::size_t Idx = 0,
         typename... TagsSrc, typename... ValsSrc,
         typename... TagsDst, typename... ValsDst>
constexpr std::enable_if_t<Idx == sizeof...(TagsDst), void> copy_to(
        tagged_tuple_impl<pack<TagsSrc...>, pack<ValsSrc...>> const& /*src*/,
        tagged_tuple_impl<pack<TagsDst...>, pack<ValsDst...>>& /*dst*/) {
    // Nothing left to do
}

/**
 * TagsSrc... is subset of TagsDst... so use copy_from
 */
template<typename... TagsSrc, typename... ValsSrc,
         typename... TagsDst, typename... ValsDst>
constexpr std::enable_if_t<
    all_true<
        is_subset_of<pack<TagsSrc...>, pack<TagsDst...>>::value,
        !is_subset_of<pack<TagsDst...>, pack<TagsSrc...>>::value // need this to handle reorder case
    >::value,void>
copy_impl(
        tagged_tuple_impl<pack<TagsSrc...>, pack<ValsSrc...>> const& src,
        tagged_tuple_impl<pack<TagsDst...>, pack<ValsDst...>>& dst) {
    copy_from(src, dst);
}
/**
 * TagsSrc... is subset of TagsDst... so use copy_to
 */
template<typename... TagsSrc, typename... ValsSrc,
         typename... TagsDst, typename... ValsDst>
constexpr std::enable_if_t<is_subset_of<pack<TagsDst...>, pack<TagsSrc...>>::value, void> copy_impl(
        tagged_tuple_impl<pack<TagsSrc...>, pack<ValsSrc...>> const& src,
        tagged_tuple_impl<pack<TagsDst...>, pack<ValsDst...>>& dst) {
    copy_to(src, dst);
}

/**
 * Check if copying is allowed by CopyingPolicy.
 */
template<class CopyingPolicy = detail::copying_policy_flexible,
         typename... TagsSrc, typename... ValsSrc,
         typename... TagsDst, typename... ValsDst>
constexpr void copy(
        tagged_tuple_impl<pack<TagsSrc...>, pack<ValsSrc...>> const& src,
        tagged_tuple_impl<pack<TagsDst...>, pack<ValsDst...>>& dst) {
//    static_assert(CopyingPolicy::is_copyable(src, dst), "Copying tagged_tuple not possible.");
    static_assert(
                CopyingPolicy::template is_copyable_t<
                    pack<TagsSrc...>, pack<ValsSrc...>, pack<TagsDst...>, pack<ValsDst...>
                    >::value,
                  "Copying tagged_tuple not possible.");
    copy_impl(src, dst);
}

template<typename... Tags, typename... Vals>
struct tagged_tuple_impl<pack<Tags...>, pack<Vals...>> : std::tuple<Vals...> {

    template <typename... Args>
    constexpr tagged_tuple_impl(Args&&... args) : std::tuple<Vals...>(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {
        // check if all tags are unique
        static_assert(is_unique<Tags...>::value, "All Tags in tagged_tuple must be unique.");
    }

    template<typename Tag>
    constexpr at_t<find<Tag, Tags...>::value, Vals...> const& get() const {
        return std::get<find<Tag, Tags...>::value>(*this);
    }
    template<typename Tag>
    constexpr at_t<find<Tag, Tags...>::value, Vals...>& get() {
        return std::get<find<Tag, Tags...>::value>(*this);
    }
};

} // end namespace detail

template<typename... Ts>
struct tagged_tuple : detail::tagged_tuple_impl<
            detail::extract_tags_t<Ts...>,
            detail::extract_vals_t<Ts...>
        > {

    // typedefs for convenience
    using Tags = detail::extract_tags_t<Ts...>;
    using Vals = detail::extract_vals_t<Ts...>;
    using Impl = detail::tagged_tuple_impl<Tags, Vals>;
    using Self = tagged_tuple<Ts...>;

    using CopyingPolicy = detail::copying_policy_flexible;

    //
    template<typename... Args,
             std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<pack<std::decay_t<Args>...>, Vals>::value || sizeof...(Args) == 0>* =
                 nullptr>
    constexpr tagged_tuple(Args... args) : Impl(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}

    template<typename... TagsOther, typename... ValsOther>
    constexpr tagged_tuple(detail::tagged_tuple_impl<pack<TagsOther...>, pack<ValsOther...>> const& other) {
        detail::copy<CopyingPolicy>(other, *this);
    }
    template<typename... TagsOther, typename... ValsOther>
    constexpr Self& operator=(detail::tagged_tuple_impl<pack<TagsOther...>, pack<ValsOther...>> const& other) {
        detail::copy<CopyingPolicy>(other, *this);
        return *this;
    }
};

template<typename Tag, typename... Tags, typename... Vals>
constexpr at_t<find<Tag, Tags...>::value, Vals...>&
get(detail::tagged_tuple_impl<pack<Tags...>,pack<Vals...>>& t) {
    return t.template get<Tag>();
}
template<typename Tag, typename... Tags, typename... Vals>
constexpr at_t<find<Tag, Tags...>::value, Vals...> const&
get(detail::tagged_tuple_impl<pack<Tags...>,pack<Vals...>> const& t) {
    return t.template get<Tag>();
}

} // end namespace tt


#endif // TAGGED_TUPLE_HPP
```

Comment: Which standard are you targeting?  Your `all_true` seems to suggest that you are in the pre-C++17 era.

Comment: @L.F. Thanks for your reply, I was not aware of any build-in trait to check for truth of a pack of bools. Could you please tell me more about this?

Comment: Oh, we have [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) in C++17 `(Bools && ...)` and also [`std::conjunction`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conjunction).

Comment: @L.F. Yes of course! My mind was stuck in c++14, thanks for the tip :)